# get event's creator email using facebook api graph

Tags: facebook, api, events

I'm using fb api to get events from a location, and i can obtain event's data.
In retrived data there aren't emails of the event's creators or other data can help me to obtain emails.
how can i retrieve?

Comment: You can’t get a user’s email, unless they login to your app and grant it permission.

Comment: thank you CBroe. Some days ago i published an event on fb and 1 day after, a web site sent me a mail (at address of the event's creator) to say me that my event was published on web site. I haven't grant permission ... how is it possible?

Comment: Your event creator, is that a user profile, or a page?

Comment: creator is a page

Comment: Well in that case, simply `page-id?fields=emails` ...